# VideoPlayer freezes the app

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a subclassed VideoView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayerView extends VideoView {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayerView";

    public VideoPlayerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VideoPlayerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VideoPlayerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void release() {
    }

    public void playVideo() {
        setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"));
        start();
    }
}
```

And a few XML layouts that use it in this manner:

```
<my.package.path.ui.common.VideoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"/>
```

I call playVideo in parent activity's onCreate(). The problem is that, if I hit the back button before the video is ready, the app stops responding for about 10-20 seconds and I can see the following in LogCat:

```
07-31 08:30:42.049: V/MediaPlayerService(18684): [1] reset
07-31 08:30:42.049: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(18684): disconnect()
07-31 08:30:42.057: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(18684): onDisconnectComplete() mState = 0
07-31 08:30:42.065: A/(18684): frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/foundation/ABuffer.cpp:58 CHECK_LE( offset + size,mCapacity) failed: 4294967288 vs. 262824
07-31 08:30:42.065: A/libc(18684): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
07-31 08:30:42.315: I/power(179): *** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1 
07-31 08:30:42.315: D/PowerManagerService(179): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
07-31 08:30:42.315: W/ActivityManager(179): mDVFSLock.release()
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475): SET
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/espresso10wifixx/espresso10wifi:4.0.3/IML74K/P5110XXALB7:eng/test-keys'
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475): pid: 18684, tid: 18697  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  r0 deadbaad  r1 00000001  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  r4 00000000  r5 00000027  r6 01ff81c0  r7 fffffff8
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  r8 00000000  r9 00000001  10 413df629  fp 0000001e
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  ip ffffffff  sp 42356870  lr 400f20a9  pc 400ee808  cpsr 60000030
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d0  2e73762038383220  d1  6574636f2f6e6f32
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d2  6f632e656c707036  d3  656e6f6870692f32
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d4  73656c706d61732f  d5  2f706f627069622f
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d6  69662f3172616567  d7  0000001e6553656c
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d8  00000000000402a8  d9  412021a600000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d10 416312d000000000  d11 4014000000000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d16 4187d78400000000  d17 41f1406280400000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d18 3fe0000000000000  d19 3fe0000000000a28
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d20 3f1149942ce213d7  d21 bebba8a21867784d
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 3fe6c310da4e22ec
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d24 3e66376972bea4d0  d25 0000000000000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
07-31 08:30:42.573: I/DEBUG(6475):  scr 20000010
07-31 08:30:42.651: W/PowerManagerService(179): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x3
07-31 08:30:42.651: I/PowerManagerService(179): Ulight 7->3|0
07-31 08:30:42.651: D/PowerManagerService(179): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 0
07-31 08:30:42.760: I/DEBUG(6475):          #00  pc 00017808  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.760: I/DEBUG(6475):          #01  pc 0000144a  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert)
07-31 08:30:42.760: I/DEBUG(6475):          #02  pc 000061ac  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android7ABuffer8setRangeEjj)
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):          #03  pc 000ed0f8  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android11LiveSession9fetchFileEPKcPNS_2spINS_7ABufferEEEjd)
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): code around pc:
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400ee7e8 4623b15c 2c006824 e026d1fb b12368db  \.#F$h.,..&..h#.
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400ee7f8 21014a17 6011447a 48124798 24002527  .J.!zD.`.G.H'%.$
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400ee808 f7f47005 2106eec4 ef52f7f5 460aa901  .p.....!..R....F
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400ee818 f04f2006 94015380 94029303 eb1cf7f5  . O..S..........
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400ee828 4622a905 f7f52002 f7f4eb26 2106eeb0  .."F. ..&......!
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): code around lr:
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400f2088 41f0e92d 46804c0c 447c2600 68a56824  -..A.L.F.&|D$h.h
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400f2098 e0076867 300cf9b5 dd022b00 47c04628  gh.....0.+..(F.G
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400f20a8 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f4 d1ee2c00  .CT5...7..$h.,..
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400f20b8 e8bd4630 bf0081f0 00028472 41f0e92d  0F......r...-..A
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): 400f20c8 fb01b086 9004f602 461f4815 4615460c  .........H.F.F.F
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): memory map around addr deadbaad:
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): be80a000-be82b000 [stack]
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): (no map for address)
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): stack:
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356830  0004c61f  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356834  00000380  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356838  ffff0208  [vectors]
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235683c  4235689c  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356840  4011a72c  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356844  4011f828  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356848  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235684c  400f20a9  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356850  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356854  42356884  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356858  01ff81c0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235685c  fffffff8  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356860  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356864  400f1215  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356868  df0027ad  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235686c  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475): #00 42356870  4235686c  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356874  00000001  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356878  400d5575  /system/lib/liblog.so
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235687c  00000001  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356880  4235689c  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356884  fffffbdf  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356888  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.776: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235688c  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356890  42356cbc  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356894  400d444d  /system/lib/liblog.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475): #01 42356898  42356cac  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235689c  6d617266  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568a0  726f7765  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568a4  622f736b  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568a8  2f657361  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568ac  6964656d  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568b0  696c2f61  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568b4  61747362  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568b8  72666567  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568bc  74686769  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568c0  756f662f  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568c4  7461646e  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568c8  2f6e6f69  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568cc  66754241  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568d0  2e726566  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568d4  3a707063  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568d8  43203835  /dev/ashmem/AudioFlinger::Client (deleted)
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568dc  4b434548  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568e0  28454c5f  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568e4  66666f20  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568e8  20746573  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568ec  6973202b  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568f0  6d2c657a  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568f4  61706143  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568f8  79746963  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423568fc  61662029  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356900  64656c69  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356904  3234203a  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356908  36393439  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235690c  38383237  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356910  2e737620  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356914  32363220  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356918  00343238  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235691c  65757165  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356920  3165636e  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356924  0073742e  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356928  42356998  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235692c  944d19e8  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356930  01fe5df4  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356934  415f4918  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356938  424bdc90  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235693c  41481069  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356940  42356998  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356944  41482719  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356948  000003ff  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235694c  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356950  00000022  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356954  00000004  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356958  0000137b  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235695c  01f48000  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356960  01fe6268  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356964  944d19e8  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356968  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235696c  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356970  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356974  41481001  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356978  423569d0  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235697c  41482719  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356980  415f4918  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356984  01fe5df0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356988  003569a4  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235698c  00000053  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356990  423569a4  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356994  402c127c  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356998  01fe5df0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     4235699c  00000068  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569a0  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569a4  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569a8  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569ac  00000001  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569b0  402c18f0  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569b4  400ed037  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569b8  402c127c  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569bc  01ff1da0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569c0  415f4918  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569c4  401265e8  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569c8  424bdc90  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569cc  424bdd60  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569d0  01f49068  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569d4  01f49068  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569d8  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569dc  414a5b99  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569e0  415f4918  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569e4  01fe5df0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569e8  00356a58  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569ec  944d19e8  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569f0  01fe5df4  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569f4  415f4918  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569f8  424bdc90  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     423569fc  41481069  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a00  42356a58  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a04  41482719  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a08  424bdc90  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a0c  402bba2f  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a10  42356a44  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a14  00000046  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a18  01feaaa0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a1c  01feaae6  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a20  01ffbee0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a24  402bba47  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a28  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a2c  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a30  402c127c  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a34  01f490f8  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a38  42356a7c  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a3c  402c1898  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a40  0000000e  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a44  01f49068  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a48  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a4c  402bba2f  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a50  424bdd38  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a54  01f48c9c  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a58  42356ac0  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a5c  00000014  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a60  01f49068  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a64  402bba47  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a68  424bdd38  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a6c  4147d1d1  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a70  424bdd38  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a74  4147e78f  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a78  424bdd5c  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a7c  00000078  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a80  01f48c88  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a84  41481791  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a88  42356af8  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a8c  944d19e8  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a90  01fe5df4  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a94  415f4918  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a98  424bdc90  
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356a9c  41481069  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.783: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356aa0  42356af8  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356aa4  41482719  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356aa8  424bdc90  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356aac  402bba2f  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ab0  42356ae4  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ab4  00000047  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ab8  01feaa58  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356abc  01feaa9f  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ac0  02003ce8  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ac4  402bba47  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ac8  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356acc  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ad0  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ad4  402c1801  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ad8  402c1898  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356adc  0000000c  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ae0  01fe6268  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ae4  01fd7638  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ae8  424bdc90  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356aec  402bb8b5  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356af0  41405d8c  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356af4  42356b98  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356af8  01fe5df0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356afc  42356b1c  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b00  01fe6268  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b04  402bb8c7  /system/lib/libstlport.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b08  41405d8c  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b0c  413ba783  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b10  41405d8c  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b14  413bb47b  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b18  01fd76a8  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b1c  413f8b8c  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b20  413ead72  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b24  000001a4  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b28  01fd76a8  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b2c  01feaaa0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b30  ffffffe6  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b34  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b38  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b3c  01feaa9f  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b40  01feaa58  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b44  400e9401  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b48  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b4c  00000004  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b50  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b54  ffffffff  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b58  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.791: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b5c  ffffffff  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b60  00000007  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b64  00000013  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b68  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b6c  ffffffff  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b70  0000001a  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b74  0000002d  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b78  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b7c  ffffffff  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b80  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b84  ffffffff  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b88  01fd7638  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b8c  4011f4c8  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b90  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b94  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b98  01ff1e08  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356b9c  413deea1  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ba0  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ba4  400ec9e9  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ba8  01ff1de7  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bac  01ff1da0  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bb0  32348101  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bb4  36323439  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bb8  34323832  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bbc  944d19e8  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bc0  ffffffff  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bc4  000402a8  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bc8  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bcc  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bd0  412021a6  /system/lib/libcaps.so
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bd4  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bd8  42356c7c  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bdc  42356cc8  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356be0  fffffff8  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356be4  01ff81d4  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356be8  00000001  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bec  413df629  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bf0  02027b78  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bf4  4011f540  
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bf8  01fe6268  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.799: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356bfc  01fe62e8  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c00  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c04  4011f4b8  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c08  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c0c  400ebb85  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c10  01ff1370  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c14  4011f4c8  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c18  00000010  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c1c  4011f494  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c20  01ff1378  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c24  00000001  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c28  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c2c  400ec9e9  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c30  01ff1378  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c34  00000080  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c38  00000010  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c3c  01fe6268  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c40  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c44  00000001  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c48  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c4c  400ecf3d  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c50  42356cbc  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c54  0000006a  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c58  01fe6268  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c5c  0000006a  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c60  40893e60  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c64  fffffff8  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c68  00000000  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c6c  40110951  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c70  42356cbc  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c74  40893195  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c78  42356cbc  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c7c  0000006a  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c80  01fe62d2  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c84  40110959  /system/lib/libc.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c88  42356cbc  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c8c  40893195  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c90  42356cbc  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c94  42356cc8  
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c98  02006510  [heap]
07-31 08:30:42.807: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356c9c  944d19e8  
07-31 08:30:42.815: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ca0  42356cc8  
07-31 08:30:42.815: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ca4  408911af  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
07-31 08:30:42.815: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356ca8  40893d3e  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
07-31 08:30:42.815: I/DEBUG(6475):     42356cac  01fe6268  [heap]
07-31 08:30:45.198: D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(18684): Entering AudioStreamOutALSA standby mode
07-31 08:30:45.198: I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(18684): Close
07-31 08:30:45.619: I/DEBUG(6475): EET
07-31 08:30:45.619: I/DEBUG(6475): !@dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 18684
07-31 08:30:45.619: I/BootReceiver(179): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
07-31 08:30:45.619: I/dumpstate(18714): begin
07-31 08:30:45.737: D/dalvikvm(179): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1199K, 21% free 14383K/18183K, paused 1ms+25ms
07-31 08:30:51.315: W/ActivityManager(179): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-31 08:30:51.330: W/ActivityManager(179): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{419e84a0 com.missiondata.tcu/.ui.course.CourseActivity}
07-31 08:30:54.041: D/VoldCmdListener(87): asec list
07-31 08:30:54.041: D/VoldCmdListener(87): CommandListener::AsecCmd::runCommand -> -- 
07-31 08:30:57.041: I/dumpstate(18714): done
07-31 08:30:57.112: W/AudioSystem(179): AudioPolicyService server died!
07-31 08:30:57.112: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(18600): release
07-31 08:30:57.112: V/MediaPlayer(18600): setListener
07-31 08:30:57.112: V/MediaPlayer(18600): disconnect
07-31 08:30:57.119: W/AudioSystem(179): AudioFlinger server died!
07-31 08:30:57.119: I/ServiceManager(86): service 'media.audio_policy' died
07-31 08:30:57.119: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(18600): media server died
07-31 08:30:57.119: V/MediaPlayer(18600): died
07-31 08:30:57.119: V/MediaPlayer(18600): message received msg=100, ext1=100, ext2=0
07-31 08:30:57.119: E/MediaPlayer(18600): error (100, 0)
07-31 08:30:57.119: V/MediaPlayer(18600): destructor
07-31 08:30:57.119: V/MediaPlayer(18600): disconnect
07-31 08:30:57.119: W/AudioSystem(18600): AudioFlinger server died!
07-31 08:30:57.119: I/ServiceManager(86): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
07-31 08:30:57.119: I/ServiceManager(86): service 'media.player' died
07-31 08:30:57.119: I/ServiceManager(86): service 'media.camera' died
07-31 08:30:57.127: D/OpenGLRenderer(18600): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

This is very consistent and predictable. I don't believe it is related to the stream as I was able to reproduce the problem with other LIVE HTTP sources too. Do you see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: In which sdk version are you trying this?

Comment: A few more lines of the log leading up to the error: http://pastebin.com/N8jz5pmt

Comment: 3.2 Running on a 10" Galaxy with 4.x

Comment: I have reports for other Samsung devices too.

Comment: I am **not** subclassing VideoView but am experiencing the same issues on multiple devices, it's due to mediaserver dying when unable to connect to the stream. It's incredibly stupid to have that kind of behavior, especially when it freezes the UI for way more than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

My options:
1,Don't extend VideoView class.Use VideoView directly.
2,When your app be paused,let videoview pause.When your app resume,let  videoview resume.My mean is that u should sync app state with video view state.

Hope my options help you.Good luck.^-^